# ¿Cómo Abrir las capetas principales de windows con c#?

Tags: c#, windows

Tengo la siguiente línea:

```
System.Diagnostics.Process.Start("explorer ",reader["ruta"].ToString());`
```

La cual es para abrir una de las carpetas principales cómo:

> - Documentos
> - Música
> - Imágenes

Para el caso de música ejecuta  `explorer music`, para videos `explorer videos`.

El problema es que siempre se abre la carpeta de documentos.

Los comandos los he probado directamente desde el *cmd*, y ahí sí que funcionan.

Comment: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.environment.specialfolder(v=vs.110).aspx

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Usa la clase Environment.SpecialFolder para obtener la ruta aquí te envío un ejemplo con la carpeta Mis Documentos:

```
            string rutaMisDocumentos = Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.MyDocuments);

        System.Diagnostics.Process.Start("explorer.exe", rutaMisDocumentos);
```